# Saving the opened file in particular folder

Tags: c#

I want to open a file from specific folder abc, make changes in it and store it in another folder load. How can I do this in c#.net?

My code is like this but not able to store it in another folder

```
string myPath = @"C:\Users\Presentation1.pptx"; 
System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
prc.StartInfo.FileName = myPath; 
prc.Start();
```

Comment: You're looking for the `File` class.

Comment: First of all, what kind of app/website/service or whatever you're trying to develop?

Comment: You could look at the MSDN info about FileStream class. [MSDN - Filestream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it work. For word document I saved as

```
object fileName = path + file + ".docx";
             wordDoc.SaveAs (ref fileName,
             ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
             ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
             ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
             ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
             ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
             ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
             ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
             ref objMissing);
```

For excel sheet i Saved as

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

for ppt I saved as

```
objPres.SaveAs(fileName, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Office.msoTrue);
```